# Kotlin: Sum of BigDecimal in a list

Tags: kotlin

I have a list that I want to filter, then return a map of id with sum of amounts:

```
val totalById = list
                    .filter { it.status == StatusEnum.Active }
                    .groupBy { it.item.id }
                    .mapValues { it.value.sumBy { it.amount } }
```

"it.amount" is BigDecimal, but looks like sumBy is Int only.

For java 8 it'd be:

`Collectors.groupingBy(i-> i.getItem().getId(), Collectors.mapping(Item::getAmount, Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))))`

Is there a way to do it in Kotlin?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just like you've used `Collectors.reducing` in java, you can use `fold` or `reduce` extension functions in Kotlin:

```
val bigDecimals: List<BigDecimal> = ...
val sum = bigDecimals.fold(BigDecimal.ZERO) { acc, e -> acc + e }
// or
val sum2 = bigDecimals.fold(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
```

The full example on play.kotlinlang.org: https://pl.kotl.in/o6pRhrqys

Starting with **Kotlin 1.4** there's now a function [`sumOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-of.html), that takes a selector function and sums all values returned by this selector, so you can use it as following:

```
val totalById = list
                .groupBy { it.id }
                .mapValues { it.value.sumOf { it.amount } }
```

The full example on play.kotlinlang.org: https://pl.kotl.in/jXAfoyff-

Comment: I tried: 
.mapValues { it.value.map { it.amount}.fold(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add) 

but complierr complain "::add":

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:

Comment: [ERROR] private open fun add(p0: BigInteger!, p1: Int, p2: BigInteger!, p3: Int): BigDecimal! defined in java.math.BigDecimal
[ERROR] private open fun add(p0: Long, p1: Int, p2: BigInteger!, p3: Int): BigDecimal! defined in java.math.BigDecimal
[ERROR] private open fun add(p0: Long, p1: Int, p2: Long, p3: Int): BigDecimal! defined in java.math.BigDecimal
[ERROR] private open fun add(p0: Long, p1: Long): Long defined in java.math.BigDecimal
[ERROR] private open fun add(p0: Long, p1: Long, p2: Int): BigDecimal! defined in java.math.BigDecimal

Comment: @klc, I've crafted a complete example and it works: http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/cpohvnjtfr0uvpvcjc3gt02b1t/n0j3v72oh55hdf141663os6eek, you can try it yourself there.

Comment: thanks for the example, i can't get it compile in intellij though....will look into it....
The first way works!

Answer (score 10):

You can create your own `sumByBigDecimal` [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) similar to [`sumByDouble`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by-double.html). e.g.:

```
/**
 * Returns the sum of all values produced by [selector] function applied to each element in
 * the collection.
 */
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.sumByBigDecimal(selector: (T) -> BigDecimal): BigDecimal {
    var sum: BigDecimal = BigDecimal.ZERO
    for (element in this) {
        sum += selector(element)
    }
    return sum
}
```

Example usage:

```
val totalById = list
        .filter { it.status == StatusEnum.Active }
        .groupBy { it.item.id }
        .mapValues { it.value.sumByBigDecimal { it.amount } }
```

Comment: Is there a way to make inline function global? As you can see this sumByBigDecimal is used accross the whole application.

Comment: the function is global by default @klc.  It can be imported and used anywhere.

Answer (score 9):

In Kotlin 1.4 they introduced `sumOf`, usage of it:

```
val bigDecimals: List<BigDecimal> = ...
val sum = bigDecimals.sumOf { it }
```

[documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-of.html)

Comment: This should be the right/best answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Combining the fold approach and the extension function approach, you can do this:

```
fun Iterable<BigDecimal>.sumByBigDecimal(): BigDecimal {
    return this.fold(BigDecimal.ZERO) { acc, e -> acc + e }
}

fun <T> Iterable<T>.sumByBigDecimal(transform: (T) -> BigDecimal): BigDecimal {
    return this.fold(BigDecimal.ZERO) { acc, e -> acc + transform.invoke(e) }
}
```

Use them like this:

```
listOfBigs.sumByBigDecimal()

listOfWidgets.sumByBigDecimal { it.price }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is not empty, you can also use `reduce`:

```
val bigDecimals: List<BigDecimal> = ...
val sum = bigDecimals.reduce(BigDecimal::add)
```

If the list can be empty, than you need `fold` and `BigDecimal.ZERO`, just like the accepted answer suggests.